# Video progress bar will not go away in full screen

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube, fullscreen, progress

At the beginning of the summer I started to have a problem with YouTube where the progress bar would not disappear in full screen. I just refreshed the page and it would go away.

Now, if I change any video settings, like the quality, it will do the same thing. I have to refresh the page again.

After a while it started to not fix after I refreshed the page.

Why is it doing this?

[image: image of progress bar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you do is hover your mouse to the lower left corner of the screen where the play button is, the progress bar should disappear in 1-3 seconds.

Comment: ^my thoughts exactly!